# Azure VM's Accessing/Managing

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

I am aiming to be able to access and manage VM's in Azure. The aim is so me to log in (az login) through the CLI into my own account and be granted full access and privileges to another subscription so I can spin up, shut down, access etc. 
Is this possible? and if yes how?

Comment: In fact, you need invite your user to the subscription and give `Owner` role on subscription level. See this link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-admin-add-users

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible I have done it through azure powershell. I have deployed a couple of VMs that I can manage. Please use the following links to get familiar with it:

[Get started with Azure PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/get-started-azureps?view=azurermps-4.4.1)

[Stop-AzureVM (Azure) | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/stop-azurevm?view=azuresmps-4.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is right, it is possible.

But you need invite your user to the subscription(B2B), the steps to do this, you could check this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-admin-add-users).

What is Azure AD B2B collaboration? You could check this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-what-is-azure-ad-b2b).

As hannel said, after you invite the user to a subscription, you need give `Owner` role on subscription level, then you could use Azure CLi to manage your VM.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use PowerShell or CLI to manage resources on another subscription, the owner of that subscription need to give you owner rights or if it's just to stop/start VM then Virtual Machine contributor rights to that subscription.

[image]

Once you have rights to the subscription can them use PowerShell, cli, or ...... to manage (stop/start) VM.  'Access' is granted on OS level so that is not managed on Azure except you are using Azure AD DS.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has said, so long as your account is granted appropriate rights on the subscription then you will be able to manage the VM using the CLI. Once you login to the CLI you will select the subscription and then manage as normal.

For stoping and staring the VM you only need limited rights so you can be granted either the VM contributor role or a custom role that just has those actions.

Where it is a bit more complicated is access the VM it’s self using RDP or SSH. You will need to be provided credentials to access the machine, these will not be provided through the portal or CLI unless you choose to reset them, which may not be appreciated if others are using this VM.